# facebook app only on facebook canvas

Tags: php, facebook

I want my facebook app to be accessed only on facebook canvas but not on my website. Right now, if I access http://mywebdomain.com/facebook/ the application is displayed but I want to redirect the user to https://apps.facebook/myApp/

My facebook object is "simple", something like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'xxx',
'secret' => 'yyy',
'cookie' => true
));
```

Comment: and your facebook object does not have to be any complex than this :p

Comment: the domain where you have hosted your facebook application i.e. ` http://mywebdomain.com/facebook/`, should be having **https**. otherwise facebook wont allow your app to be displayed in their canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] to see what address has been used to access your page, and if necessary, do a 301 redirect to the https://apps.facebook/myApp/

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "Your domain") {
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: https://apps.facebook/myApp/"); 
}
else
{
... your app goes here. 
}
?>
```

Before you implement the redirect though, I would just create a test page which displayed the value of $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], and access the code from within facebook and directly from your site. If they are different then you are fine.

I will test this myself, just to be on the safe side.

EDIT

Actually, I've just done some tests, and you need to check for the presence of $_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"] instead.

If you are calling from facebook, it will exist, and contain the facebook link. If you are coming from the site itself, it won't exist.

To get a good idea of what is going on, make this your first program:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SERVER);
echo "</pre>";
```

That's how I spotted HTTP_ORIGIN.

Then you should replace the above with:

```
<?php

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_ORGIN'] === "https://apps.facebook.com"){
... your app.
}
else
{
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: https://apps.facebook/myApp/");
}
```

As an alternative to HTTP_ORIGIN, you could use HTTP_REFERER, which should contain the full url and not just the facebook component. Otherwise somebody else could set up a facebook application and link to your content.

Comment: Please see my amendment. Its actually HTTP_ORIGIN you need to look for.